# LINQ Query multiple orderby of joined tables

Tags: c#, linq

I have following LinQ query

```
   var CGTABLE = (from cg in DbContext.CGTABLE
                              join tcg in DbContext.TCGTABLE on new { cg.CGroupId } equals new { tcg.CGroupId }                                                                    
                              where tcg.TId == TId
                              select new  {
                                  CGroupId = cg.CGroupId,
                                  CGroupCode = cg.CGroupCode,                                      
                                  Description = cg.Description,                                      
                                  C = cg.C,
                                  DisplayOrder = cg.DisplayOrder
                              }).ToList();

        CGTABLE = CGTABLE.OrderBy(g => g.DisplayOrder).ThenBy(g => g.C.OrderBy(c => c.CCode)).ToList();
```

which runs fine, but it is not doing second orderby using ThenBy `ThenBy(g => g.C.OrderBy(c => c.CCode)` What am I missing?

```
Sample data for better understanding.
Data in Tables
2
  1
  2
  4
  3
1
  4
  5
  2
  1
3
  3
  1

Should output after both outer and inner list ordered by
1
  1
  2
  3
  4
2
  1
  2
  4
  5
3
  1
  3

But Currently it is showing
1
  4
  5
  2
  1
2
  1
  2
  4
  3
3
  3
  1
```

Comment: Did you tried CGTABLE = CGTABLE.OrderBy(g => g.DisplayOrder).OrderBy(c => c.CCode).ToList();?

Comment: Does not work because CCode column is in C table which is separate table and C table is collection of records.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what `.ThenBy(g => g.C.OrderBy(c => c.CCode))` is meant to do. You are sorting by `g.C.OrderBy(c => c.CCode)` but that is going to be an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` and I am not sure how something can sort based on one of those... So I think you are using the wrong syntax for whatever you are trying to do but I'm not sure what you are trying to do...

Comment: I three tables joined together. I am doing order by for two columns in different tables. It returns all the required records but it is not doing the order by

Comment: Here is the query which is the closest to above script   SELECT *
FROM CGTABLE AS CG
  INNER JOIN C AS C ON CG.CGroupId  = C.CGroupId 
  INNER JOIN TCGTABLE AS TCG ON C.CGroupId  = TCG.CGroupId 
  WHERE TCG.TId = 2
  ORDER BY CG.DisplayOrder, C.CCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't want to order the main list, you are looking for a way to order inner list inside of outer one, I think.
So below code will do it for you:

```
var CGTABLE = (
    from cg in DbContext.CGTABLE
    join tcg in DbContext.TCGTABLE on new { cg.CGroupId } equals new { tcg.CGroupId }                                                                    
    where tcg.TId == TId
    select new  {
        CGroupId = cg.CGroupId,
        CGroupCode = cg.CGroupCode,                                      
        Description = cg.Description,                                      
        C = cg.C.OrderBy(x => x.CCode),
        DisplayOrder = cg.DisplayOrder
   }).ToList();

   CGTABLE = CGTABLE.OrderBy(g => g.DisplayOrder).ToList();
```

Comment: That is the problem, that I want both list order by. Top parent as well as inner list within those parent. going to update the question with data for more clearance.